# probability in normal density function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Q: let X be a continuous random variable with NORMAL DENSITY

$$f(x;\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{−(x−\mu)^2/ 2\sigma^2}$$

We know that $\mu = 70$ and $\sigma = 2$.

Find $P(68 \leq X \leq 74)$ and $P(X \geq 73)$:

my approach is ...
Since above is normal distribution..

$$
P\left(\dfrac{a-μ}{σ} \leq Z \leq \dfrac{b-μ}{σ}\right)
= P(1 \leq Z \leq 2) 
= P(Z\leq2) - P(Z\leq1)
$$

but this was wrong because the density function is not standard distribution so I could not use   the table. How can I solve this ?

Comment: [Wikipedia / Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution) gives you the Formula for adapting to the standard normal distribution.

Comment: First, the formula you gave for the normal density is _incorrect_ and I have corrected it.  For the calculation of the probabilities, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/202612/15941) for how to work such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but I think you wanted $P(-1\le Z\le2)$ instead of
$P(1\le Z\le2)$; so this would give $P(-1\le Z\le0)+P(0\le Z\le2)=P(0\le Z\le1)+P(0\le Z\le2)$.

For the second part, you want to find $P(Z\ge1.5)=1/2-P(0\le Z\le1.5)$.