# The probability that a joint distribution is less than a certain value, given the correlation coefficient.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

For this problem, we are told that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normally distributed variables, both being standard normal. We're given their correlation coefficient. So, how do I get from there to finding the probability that $X$ + $Y$ $<$ **0.7**?

What I've worked out so far is that the $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$ equals the correlation coefficient since $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal (because the standard deviations are $1$), which is also equal the $E[XY]$ (because the means are $0$). But where do I go from here...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $X+Y$ is a normal random variable since $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal.
Work out its mean and variance and look up the answer in tables.

Comment: Okay... So I get that the mean is then 0, and the standard deviation is the square root of 2. But what tables are you referring to?

Comment: If you have been taught _anything_ at all about normal random variables before being assigned this problem, you would have been told about the _cumulative probability distribution function_ of the standard normal random variable, and tables of the values of this function. You might even have been taught how to use the table for _other_ (nonstandard) normal random variables such as $X+Y$ here, but if not, read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/202612/15941) for a detailed description of how to use the table.